# Copying a Kotlin array minus the element at a particular index

Tags: generics, kotlin, types

I'm trying to write a Kotlin function to copy an array with one element chopped out. This is what I've got so far:

```
inline fun <reified T> minusIndex(s: Array<T>, i: Int): Array<T> {
    val r = arrayOfNulls<T>(s.size - 1)
    System.arraycopy(s, 0, r, 0, i)
    System.arraycopy(s, i + 1, r, i, r.size - i)
    return r.requireNoNulls()
}
```

It initially wouldn't make an array of type `T`, but is happy with that part once the `inline` and `reified` keywords are added.

It won't return `r` straight, because `r` is of type `Array<T?>` and I want to return `Array<T>`, okay, that's understandable.

But `requireNoNulls` doesn't work; it seems to be saying it wants `Any` and is getting `T` instead, which seems to be a subtler quirk of the type system than is covered by my understanding carried across from Java.

What am I doing wrong, and what's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requireNoNulls()` returns an array with a non-nullable type. Your code shows an error because the resulting array's type is definitely non-nullable, but your function is supposed to return an `Array<T>` where `T` is potentially nullable.

To specify that `T` is non-nullable, you can specify that it extends `Any` rather than the default of `Any?`.

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> minusIndex(s: Array<T>, i: Int): Array<T> {
    val r = arrayOfNulls<T>(s.size - 1)
    System.arraycopy(s, 0, r, 0, i)
    System.arraycopy(s, i + 1, r, i, r.size - i)
    return r.requireNoNulls()
}
```

However, if you want to allow this function to work even on arrays with a nullable type, you will have to cast `r` to `T`. You can suppress the unchecked cast warning. We know it's a safe cast because you've filled every index of the new array with some element of type `T`, whether or not it's nullable:

```
inline fun <reified T> minusIndex(s: Array<T>, i: Int): Array<T> {
    val r = arrayOfNulls<T>(s.size - 1)
    System.arraycopy(s, 0, r, 0, i)
    System.arraycopy(s, i + 1, r, i, r.size - i)
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return r as Array<T>
}
```